# PHP how to output the top array_count_values value from array?

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have a table that I need to find "top trusted builder" from, Trusts are separated by " ; ", So I need to pull all the data, explode the usernames, order and count them, and Im stuck on finally outputting the top username form the array, I have posted up the full segment of PHP, because im sure there has to be a much better way of doing this.

```
<?php 
$GTB = $DBH->query('SELECT builders from griefprevention_claimdata where builders <> ""');
$GMCB->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$buildersarray = array();

while($row = $GTB->fetch()) {

      $allbuilders = explode(";", $row['builders']);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($allbuilders); $i++)
          {
            $buildersarray[] = $allbuilders[$i];
          }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_count_values(array_filter($buildersarray)));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
[username1] => 4
[username2] => 1
[username3] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the array from the array_count_values command into a new array called $topbuilders, and then echo out the current (first) record:

```
$topbuilders = array_count_values(array_filter($buildersarray));
echo current(array_keys($topbuilders)).', Rank = '.current($topbuilders);
```

current() will return the first item in an associative array.

Comment: This partially worked, output was "0, Rank = username1 "
Im going to need to display their amount of trusts too..

Comment: Not sure what you mean by their "amount of trusts." Is that stored somewhere in this existing fetched array, or is that something that needs to come from a separate query?

Comment: Ok, making sense now - I edited my answer. Try it out.

Comment: This is it, Superb! Im going to now research Current, I had never heard of it. 
Thanks again, I was really stuck on getting this to work!

Comment: Hey IarsAnders, After using the segment of code with a larger sample size of data, it dousnt seems to be reporting the "most trusted" (from "builders") as a user called wkeresey, this user isnt the moste trusted. Now im stuck as I thought we managed to fix it! To help I have exported my database for you to see the structure too!
http://pastebin.com/VpVAxAMF

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `array_count_values()` it would be better to use the names as the key to a frequency array:

```
$GTB = $DBH->query('SELECT builders from griefprevention_claimdata where builders <> ""');

$result = array();

while (($builders = $GTB->fetchColumn()) !== false) {
    foreach (explode(";", $builders) as $builder) {
        if (isset($result[$builder])) {
            $result[$builder]++;
        } else {
            $result[$builder] = 1;
        }
}
// sort descending based on numeric comparison
arsort($result, SORT_NUMERIC);

echo "Name = ", key($result), " Count = ", current($result), "\n";
```